# Java Kafka producer unable to connect to broker running on WSL2 (Ubuntu for Windows command prompt)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am currently learning Kafka and I have a windows system. Therefore I installed WSL2 as its more compatible and easy to use. Below is my java code for a simple Kafka Producer

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName()); 
properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class.getName());
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("demo_java", "hello world");

producer.send(producerRecord);
producer.flush();
producer.close();
```

As per my understanding, even though Zookeeper and Kafka are running on WSL2 I should be able to connect to the broker running on localhost:9092 via the java code running on Windows. However, I get the following error

```
Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established.Broker may not be available
```

I have started Zookeper and Kafka on WSL2. I have created the topic `demo_java` as well.
It is not able to connect to the Broker I think. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I advise to read https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/ and https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: @GQuintana That link assumes all clients are running within WSL2

Comment: @OneCricketeer Not the second link, section "Scenario 4: Kafka in Docker container with a client running locally"

Comment: @GQuintana OP isn't using Docker. Please see the duplicate post I linked instead